How do I split a string inside power automate to generate an Array without empty strings
I have a Child Flow inside Power Automate, which accepts names in a semi-colon-separated string, here are examples of the string:-

;test
test;test2
test;;test2
test

Now I want to generate an array, but I do not want the array to have empty strings. can I write a single formula to do this? I have tried this:


split(variables('names'),';')

This will generate array with empty string.


union(Split(replace(replace(variables('names'), ';;', ';'), '; ', ';'), ';'), json('[]'))

The same issue above.


I do not want to do FilterArray action, as I am trying to minimize the number of actions been generated by my flows, so I am looking to do this in a single formula inside a Compose.

You may want to minimize but sometimes it’s just better to use multiple actions. It makes things more readable and gives you a nice debug layer. Why not just use the filter array step?

Other questions, does the array have unique items? Does the array have to be in its original order? Are you open to a third party connector?

@Skin this flow is a child flow that get called around 5K time per day , so doing minimal actions is needed, also i am doing this check on 5 places inside my flow.. so i do not want to add 5 filter Array actions if i can do this inside a formula. the array can contain duplicate names, but the order is not necessary at all

It's still not necessary, the built in operations run quickly, it wouldn't matter if you used multiple.  Why couldn't you do it once and reuse the results of the filter array?

@Skin Power Platform allow us to do certain limit of requests/actions per 24 hours, and i want to minimize those number of requests

So does my answer work for you?

@Skin not for all the scenarios

Just use the Filter Array action. I understand you want to keep actions to a minimum, so simply add whatever you are adding in the Compose as the Input of the Filter Array action and then you'll have your one action. What am I missing?

@SamNseir i removed the Compose and i am writing the formula directly inside the ApplyToEach . I do not want to concentrate on my current code/design of the workflow, i am trying to keep my question focus on the general issue. Split and generate an Array which does not have Empty items.. is this possible using single formula?

The answer is, the expression will be ridiculous. Supporting that approach does not sound enjoyable for anyone who may have to inherit your solution.

@Skin ok my question was if there is a way to split a string and build an array which does not contain empty strings.. assuming this should cover all scenarios. same as Split() will split any string based on the character we specified .. this could not be achieved then this is fine.

@Skin i think we are concentrating on my examples and trying to build the solution, while i am asking a general question,  on how to force the Split() to remove any empty items from the generated array.. when we study how Split() works we do not need to know all the infinite examples/cases, we know how it internally works and hence this will cover all scenarios...

Yeah, it’s not possible without wrapping things around the string, if it were possible, it would be obvious. Again, if you want to do it in a single step, use a custom connector.

@Skin but building a custom connector will require a premium license which our customer does not have at the moment. thanks anyway for your help

This will do it but it will only work with that which you've provided ...
skip(split(replace(variables('Text'), ';;', ';'), ';'), if(equals(first(split(replace(variables('Text'), ';;', ';'), ';')), ''), 1, 0))

... it will never work if you ever have more than two delimiters.  It also won't work if the delimiter exists on the end of the string.
PowerAutomate / LogicApps needs a LET() function (Excel) or a VAR() function (PowerBi) so the different components that are specified multiple times in the expression can be created and reused throughout.
There is a custom connector that can do this sort of thing with much more rigor so if you're keen on that then I can always provide an answer for it if you want but won't unless you ask.  That connector does waaaaaaay more things that you may find useful as well.

thanks for the reply. i just posted sample of the input... my question is we can Split and Remove white spaces .. this should cover scenarios where the input is '; or ;; or ;test or test; or test;;test2

We’re not mind readers, you need to show all examples of your input so we can answer your question properly. I’ve provided an answer based on your examples, as of right now, the answer to your question is maybe because your inputs are too vague. Any further complication and a single expression will be ridiculous. There is no magic way unless you look at using a third party connector or if you want to avoid limits, use LogicApps.

there are not predefined set of examples that i can provide.. my question is similar to how Split() will build an array for any string,,, i were asking if i can have a Split() that will build an Array but remove any empty items... hope this explains the case
